SVG Mask Reveal Animation Not Working on iOS 16 and macOS Safari
I've created a reveal animation using an SVG mask to reveal the content of the page. The animation works perfectly on Chrome and other browsers. However, on iPhone iOS 16 and macOS Safari, the SVG is not revealing the content as expected.
    <svg id="overlay-svg" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <filter id="displacementFilter">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" />
      </filter>
      <mask id="rectMask">
        <rect width="200" height="5" rx="2.5" ry="2.5" fill="white" class="loader-reveal" transform="translate(100 100)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    </svg>

Here's the CodePen link to my project. https://codepen.io/10daer/pen/VwJvgON
Issue Description:
The reveal animation functions correctly on Chrome and other browsers.
On iOS 16 (iPhone) and macOS Safari, the SVG mask does not reveal the content.
I've ensured the SVG and GSAP animations are correctly implemented.
The problem only persists on Safari browsers, specifically on iPhone iOS 16 and macOS.
I've tested on different devices and the issue seems consistent on Safari.
Questions:

Is there a known issue with SVG masks and animations on Safari, especially on iOS 16 and macOS?
Are there any workarounds or fixes that can ensure the reveal animation works on Safari as well?
Is there a more compatible way to implement this SVG mask reveal animation that ensures cross-browser functionality?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
I've ensured the SVG and GSAP animations are correctly implemented.
The problem only persists on Safari browsers, specifically on iPhone iOS 16 and macOS.
I've tested on different devices and the issue seems consistent on Safari.

Safari bugs can be reported here

How it should work? Because in iOS 17 on Crome and Safari works exactly the same, and I don’t see any differences. Could you provide some gif or something?

I see you are using display:none for the SVG element. Please try position:absolute instead.

You can check it on through this link https://xamlio-reveal.netlify.app/ on IOS 16 and higher
Its supposed to unmask as it's done on chrome but it didn't unmask no safari

You can check the live demo here https://xamlio-reveal.netlify.app/ to compare how it works on IOS 16 safari and chrome

@10daer Well… no difference between them, exactly the same. Maybe issue only existed on ver.16=<?

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz what do you mean by they are the same? Do you mean that both browsers rendered the website the same, that is there is no bug?
cos on safari, website content didnt come up

I meant… that whole animation looks exactly the same on those two browsers on iOS 17… I think is good idea, like I wrote before, to make gif of your issue. Then I would be able to say something more about it.

Here is the link @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz
https://imgur.com/MssoPXF

That's for the IOS 16
also, I would like to know if that is snot what you had when you viewed it on IOS 17 or probably drop a video of what you have on IOS 17 as  do not have iphone to check presently

Sure, grab one
